# Class not found when added Livewire to Custom Laravel Package

Tags: php, laravel, package

I am in the process of building a custom laravel package. I am wanting to add Livewire/Livewire as a dependency so I can use it with my package.

However I am currently experiencing the error "Class "Livewire\Livewire" not found" when i am loading the components in my package service provider.

If anyone could point in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "reachstudios/reachcontrol",
    "description": "A package for managing users",
    "keywords": [
        "reachstudios",
        "reachcontrol"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/reachstudios/reachcontrol",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "library",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jake Feeley",
            "email": "jake.feeley@reachstudios.co.uk",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Reachstudios\\ReachControl\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Reachstudios\\ReachControl\\Tests\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "vendor/bin/phpunit",
        "test-coverage": "vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage"

    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Reachstudios\\ReachControl\\ReachControlServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "ReachControl": "Reachstudios\\ReachControl\\ReachControlFacade"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Service Provider

```
<?php

namespace Reachstudios\ReachControl;

use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler;
use Livewire\Livewire;
use Reachstudios\ReachControl\Livewire\Index;
use Reachstudios\ReachControl\Middleware\CheckSessionMiddleware;

class ReachControlServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        /*
         * Optional methods to load your package assets
         */
         $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'reachcontrol');
         $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/migrations');
         $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/routes.php');

        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__.'/../config/config.php' => config_path('reachcontrol.php'),
            ], 'config');

            // Publishing the views.
            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__.'/../resources/views' => resource_path('views/vendor/reachcontrol'),
            ], 'views');

            // Publishing assets.
            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__.'/../resources/assets' => public_path('vendor/reachcontrol'),
            ], 'assets');

            // Publishing the translation files.
            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__.'/../resources/lang' => resource_path('lang/vendor/reachcontrol'),
            ], 'lang');

            // Registering package commands.
            $this->commands([]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        // Automatically apply the package configuration
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/../config/config.php', 'reachcontrol');

        // Register the main class to use with the facade
        $this->app->singleton('reachcontrol', function () {
            return new ReachControl;
        });

        // Register middleware
        $this->registerMiddleware();
        $this->registerLivewireComponents();

    }

    /**
     * Define app middleware classes.
     */
    protected function registerMiddleware(): void
    {
        app('router')->aliasMiddleware('checkSession', CheckSessionMiddleware::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register Livewire components
     */
    protected function registerLivewireComponents(): void
    {
        $this->callAfterResolving(BladeCompiler::class, function () {
            Livewire::component('index', Index::class);
         });

    }
}
```